# mysql check entry from another table before insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have this script add new users to MySql andnow I have created secondary Mysql table for black-list name. so I want MySql check the black-list name before allow insert the data.

```
$all = implode(",",$_POST);
$all = explode(",",$all);

$insert = "INSERT INTO name VALUES (";  
for ($x=0;$x<5;$x++) 
{
    $all[$x] = clean($all[$x]);
    if ($all[$x] == "" || strlen($all[$x]) > 300)
    die("<p>Please fill in the whole form." . $x);

    $insert .= "'" . $all[$x] . "',";
}

$insert .= "'')";
$res = @mysql_query($insert) ;
```

I have change to

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO name VALUES (";  
for ($x=0;$x<5;$x++) NOT IN (SELECT `blacklist` FROM `exclude`)
```

but didn't get what I am looking for. how I can fix that?

Comment: why are you doing this: for ($x=0;$x<5;$x++)  ?

Comment: what's the for loop doing in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS far as I am aware you are going to have to do a seperate select on your exclude table using whatever is the key to that table that is shared with the name table to check this user is not in the exclude list.
There is no INSERT syntax to allow a concept like INSERT unless something exists within another table.

Comment: INSERT with a LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN can do this.

Comment: I have add another SELECT before insert `$check = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `exclude` WHERE `blacklist` = '$alias'");
if (!mysql_num_rows($check)) {` then the rest of code and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, you could (ab)use `INSERT ... SELECT` to do what you want:

```
-- insert one name:
INSERT INTO user SELECT "john" FROM DUAL 
                               WHERE "john" NOT IN (SELECT name FROM blacklist);
INSERT INTO user SELECT "ringo" FROM DUAL 
                                WHERE "ringo" NOT IN (SELECT name FROM blacklist);

-- insert several names
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE candidate(name char(40));
INSERT INTO candidate VALUES
    ("paul"), ("ringo"), ("georges");

INSERT INTO user SELECT name FROM candidate 
                             WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM blacklist);
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ea68/1 for an example.